# sizing a qml qquickview inside its window container

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget

I have a QQuickView inside another widget using createWindowContainer() (see image below).  The QML scene file of the QQuickView looks something like:

```
//import related modules
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.6

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 100
    color: "red"
    ...
}
```

I can see the qml object in the QQuickView, but what I'd really like is to be able to resize the QML scene to fit the container.  I've looked at various docs and haven't found a way to reference the container in the QML scene to properly resize.  Is that possible?  Something like this?

```
Rectange {
    width: Container.width
    height: Container.height
}
```

[image: QML scene in red]

Comment: Just remove size setting and add `anchors.fill: parent` to the `Rectangle`. Another way is to set `view->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);` in C++.

Comment: The anchor fill worked.  Thanks.  If you add it as an answer I'll mark it correct.  Otherwise I'll just add the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Just remove size setting and add anchors.fill: parent to the
>   Rectangle. Another way is to set
>   view->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView); in C++

Using the solution folibis provided works great (the first one).